# Magento 2.3.4 indexing error in Catalog Search indexer

Tags: magento2, error, catalogsearch, indexing

Error when running indexing:

```
Notice: Undefined index: queries in /var/www/stage/vendor/magento/module-catalog-graph-ql/Plugin/Search/Request/ConfigReader.php on line 84
```

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this bug?  I have the same error.  When I debug the code and look at the query generated by `getSearchableAttributes()` I get 133 results in MySQL.  But it never gets into the for loop...  why???

Comment: yes in my case it was Mageplaza Admin Permissions extension issue, I was also stuck in the same case as you. But then I updated the extension and issue was resolved. Check the answer as well, that might help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the root of the issue here is that a 3rd party module we installed had a bug in it that was preventing the indexer from finding product attributes.

The module was the [MagePlaza Admin Permissions for Magento 2](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-admin-permissions/) module v1.0.0  They suggested I update to v1.0.1 and that resolved the issue.

---

In file `vendor/mageplaza/module-admin-permissions/Plugin/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Attribute/Collection.php`, function `beforeLoad()` the indexer gets into this bit of code:

```
//hide all grid columns when user haven't permission to view product
if (!$this->helperData->isAllow('Mageplaza_AdminPermissions::product_attribute_view')) {
    $collection->getSelect()->where('0=1');

    return [$printQuery, $logQuery];
}
```

Adding that where condition tells the indexer that there aren’t any product attributes to use in the indexing process and throws the error.

---

One thing I learned in debugging this is how a product collection works a bit more...  In `vendor/magento/module-catalog-graph-ql/Plugin/Search/Request/ConfigReader.php` I was analyzing the query that it is putting out where the error occurs using `$productAttributes->getSelect()->__toString()`.  When I ran that query manually I would get 133 attributes.

The next line down calls `foreach ($productAttributes->getItems() as $attribute) {` and would not get into the for loop.  How could I go from 133 to 0???

What I learned is that calling `getItems()` on a collection calls the `load()` function.  This allows other observers to modify the query.  In this case, the MagePlaza module was modifying the query via an observer.

So one debugging method that I learned here when trying to analyze the query a collection is using is to call the `load()` method before dumping out the query.

```
$collection->load();
$collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

NOTE: technically you don't need `->__toString()` as calling just `$collection->getSelect()` should work, but to me I'm used to calling the `__toString()` method from M1.

Comment: Exactly same issue with this extension. I was told to update it, so I updated it and issue was resolved. I was able to go till the for loop and was stuck there why the query was modifying. Then I contacted support and they told me to update the Mageplaza AdminPermission extension. Then it was resolved.
Thanks, for this detailed explanation.